# AngularJS, routeProvider, action vs controller

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to understand the difference between controller and action properties inside the object i pass into the when method as a second argument, I will explain:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/car.htm',
        controller : 'someControllerName'
    });
```

This example show simple controller assignment, Now my problem is with **this [link](http://clintberry.com/2013/modular-angularjs-application-design/)**, If you take a look at MainApp module definition you can see it got action property instead of controller property, **So basically:**

1. What is the difference between action and controller
2. At the MainApp module definition at the link above i don't understand why i must inject **$routeProvider and not DashboardApp**

So if anyone can help me with that i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that this is a simple typo, according to some comments

> You mean `controller: ‘DashboardApp.DashboardCtrl’` instead of
>   `action: ‘DashboardApp.DashboardCtrl’`. Correct?

---

> I wanted to thank you for this article but I wanted to address a few
>   things. I started a modular angular project and used your article to
>   get things going. I’m using AngularJS 1.2.8 and I was having issues
>   with the routing. It turns out that your example in the article
>   wouldn’t work for a modular setup. I kept getting errors saying that
>   the controllers did not exist. I changed your “action” to “controller”
>   and it still didn’t help. Here is an example of what I ended up doing:
>
> Before: $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: '/home',action:
>   'CoreApp.IndexController'});
>
> After: $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl:
>   '/home',module:'CoreApp', controller: 'IndexController'});
>
> Once i made those changes, everything worked as expected. Thanks
>   again!

Also, I checked angular [changelogs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) - there was never action parameter instead of controller. And there is no action parameter now.

Comment: Thank you Andrey for your answer i didn't saw that comment, Also can you please explain why at the MainApp module definition at the link above i don't understand why i must inject $routeProvider and not DashboardApp

Comment: @uBlankText Thats because DashboardApp - is a module, just like MainApp. And only providers may be passed to config function. You **configure** your application's routing by **configuring** $routeProvider. Checkout [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider)